# Airflow Pip install on Ubuntu 20.04 , Errno 2

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, airflow, errno

I keep getting this error on Ubuntu 20.4 running on Windows 10:

```
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
```

My Command:

```
AIRFLOW_VERSION=2.1.4
PYTHON_VERSION="$(python3 --version | cut -d " " -f 2 | cut -d "." -f 1-2)" CONSTRAINT_URL="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-${AIRFLOW_VERSION}/constraints-${PYTHON_VERSION}.txt" pip install "apache-airflow[async,postgres,google,amazon,ssh,sftp]==${AIRFLOW_VERSION}" --constraint "${CONSTRAINT_URL}
```

It is driving me crazy, and I assume it has nothing to do with the install command and is related to pip? I checked and I have pip3 installed on /user/bin, also I did ran the `sudo apt-get install python-setuptools`, and `update` commands.
Any ideas how to resolve it?

Comment: Please include the full traceback. FYI your command is missing a close quote `"`

Comment: Unable to reproduce on macOS with Python 3.9.7 Airflow 2.1.4. All packages install OK.